# How to fix `npm start` opening the wrong React app

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I have been working on a React app, let's call it app A. Then I cloned app B on a different directory and worked a little on it. The next day I went back to app A and tried `yarn start`. It opened app B on `3000`. I checked the directory, the `package.json` file, tried `npm start`. The same result. So I deleted app B from my device. To my surprise the same result. I found a workaround: I open a new terminal and run `yarn start` while app B is open, says the port is being used, do you want to open in a different port? **Yes**. Opens app A on `3001`. Its been a couple of days and still the same thing. The only thing I haven't tried is deleting `node_modules` and running `yarn` or `npm i`. Does anyone know why this happens and how it can be fixed?

Comment: This should never be a thing... have you tried like.. restarting your computer

Comment: The node process might still be running, try `lsof -i :3000` if you're on linux (or search how to find programs running on a specific port on your OS).

Comment: @bryan60 Yes, I have multiple times.

Comment: @cubrr No, no programs running.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just cleared the browser cache and everything want back to normal.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31773036)